# Data structure request: Lazily infinite set

Tags: haskell, data-structures, set, complexity-theory

Are there `F :: * -> *`, `iterate' :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> a -> F a` and `elem' :: Ord a => Int -> a -> F a -> Bool` with the following properties?

- `elem x (take n (iterate f y))` ⇒ `elem' n x (iterate' f y)` ⇒ `elem x (iterate f y)`
- `elem' n x (iterate' f y)` runs in `O(n * log n)` time and `O(n)` space
- `elem' n x xs` runs in `O(log n)` time and `O(1)` space

Comment: Condition (3) looks much stronger than condition (2), since we can choose `xs = iterate' f y`. Why is condition (2) needed if condition (3) is met? Or: what did you *actually* mean as your condition instead of condition (3)?

Comment: Free variables in a property do not take any extra time or space. `iterate' f y` is "allowed" to need what (2) states, but it wouldn't have to be evaluated that far if you never applied `elem'` to the result.

Comment: Of course, that's a very sensible stance. Understood, and thanks for the on-target answer.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a clever solution if we have prior knowledge that `iterate f` is uniformly distributed

Comment: This *kind of* thing was what I wrote [`Data.IntTrie`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie-0.1.2/docs/Data-IntTrie.html) for, though it looks quite different from your properties.  But the idea was to have an infinite fold which incrementally sorted elements into a quick access structure.  If there is a balanced isomorphism between `a` and `Int` maybe you could leverage it?

Answer (score 5):

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

type F x = [S.Set x]

iterate' f
  = map head
  . evalState (traverse (state . splitAt) (iterate (*2) 1))
  . scanl (flip S.insert) S.empty
  . iterate f

elem' n x xs = S.member x $ xs !! (ceiling (logBase 2 (fromIntegral n)) - 1)
```

(Do the intermediate sets count as allocated space? Can you even do finite sets in linear space if you need to balance them?)

Comment: This (and every other solution I can imagine) misses condition (2), since it requires at least `O(n * log n)` space to store the largest set.

Comment: @Cirdec Uhm, why? Won't a set with n elements use only O(n) space? I thought balanced BST achieved that.

Comment: Maybe if you chunk the iteration into exponentially growing portions first, you do not need so many intermediate sets, and the space can be kept O(n).

Comment: Do `S.fromList` and `S.union` take linear space? I only see time requirements there.